# FCM push notification not Receiving Doze and Deep Sleep Mode in Android

Tags: android, firebase

I'm working on a VOIP calling app. So I need a push for register sip. I'm using FCM for push. When the phone is awake everything is working. The problem starts when the phone is entering deep sleep like 2-3 hours.

I'm pushing "data" type notification with "priority":"high" and time_to_live which should wake up the device.

```
{
 'priority': 'high',
 'to': '....',
 'time_to_live': 0,
 'data': {}
}
```

I'm sending only Data Message but **onMessageReceive()** not called in deep sleep or doze mode. I tried the **IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS** but it's not working too. Seems like FCM is not reliable for VOIP push. any idea? or any suggestions? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Did you find the solution for this